# jQuery parent of a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to find the parent of a parent of an element. I have a link being clicked that is in a `<td>`, and I'd like to get the `<tr>` object.

Why wont "$(this).parent().parent()" work? What will?

Thanks,
Brendan

**Edit:** It appears an error in my syntax was throwing the whole thing off. "$(this).parent().parent()" does in fact work, but I wound up going with $(this).closest('tr')" because it seems like the most efficient solution.

Comment: could you post the code so we can see why your parent selector is not working?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

The best way would probably be using `closest`:

```
$(this).closest('tr');
```

[Check out the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest):

> Closest works by first looking at the current element to see if it matches the specified expression, if so it just returns the element itself. If it doesn't match then it will continue to traverse up the document, parent by parent, until an element is found that matches the specified expression. If no matching element is found then none will be returned.

Answer (score 20):

It should work. You can also try $(this).parents(tag) , where tag is the tag you want to find.

For example:

```
$(this).parents("tr:first")
```

Will find the closest tr "up the chain".

Answer (score 10):

That should work... you might try

```
$(this).parents(':eq(1)');
```

The .parents(selector) says get all ancestors that match the selector

and the :eq(1) says find the oneth (zero-indexed, so the second) element in the list

Comment: You might try alerting this, to make sure it is an html anchor tag.

Try doing:

    alert('anchor html(' + $(this).html() + ')');

Answer (score 9):

This snippet has performed for me in the past:

```
$(this).parent().parent();
```

Post some code for us to see if there might be another problem somewhere...

Comment: I agree with this. I can use `$(this).parent().parent()` without issue

Answer (score 5):

also try

```
$(this).closest('div.classname').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have any sort of id/class for the parent, you can use parents() but that will give you all parents up to the < body > unless you filter() or stop it some other way like

```
$(this).parents('.myClass');
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the $(this).parent() into an jQuery object like $($(this).parent()) I often find the need to do this to make sure I have a valid jquery object. From there you should be able to get a hold of the parents parent, or using the prev() perhaps.

Comment: This is completely pointless. All you're doing is wasting time by creating another jQuery object...

Answer (score 1):

```
var getParentNode = function(elem, level) { 
    level = level || 1; 
    for (var i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        if (elem != null) {
            elem = elem.parentNode; 
        }
    }
    return elem; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.closest()` is not always best option specially when you have same element construct.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can do parent of a parent and it's very easy:

```
var parent = $('.myDiv').parent();
var parentParent = $(parent).parent();
var parentParentParent = $(parentParent).parent();
```

etc.