# JS/jQuery - Get parent of iframe from child (child > iframe > parent)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, parent-child

I have a webpage that loads an iframe, which in turn loads another window, i.e: **Website** (parent) -> **iframe** (child) -> **window** (child of child?).

I need to then refer to this parent from the window (child of iframe). As this is 2 'generations' away, is there any way I can make this connection?

For reference, i've looked at window.opener methods but they don't appear to track back this far.

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966408/jquery-parent-of-a-parent

Comment: Looked at this prior to asking, completely different context