# How to access parent object in JS?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm a novice programmer and I ran into an OOP problem while programming a game in JavaScript:

It's a Bughouse Chess game. It's played by 4 players on 2 chess boards:
Each board is an independant Chess game between members of the opposing teams, the White player in one board is in a team with the Black player on the other board. When someone captures a piece, it is passed to his teammate who can then place it anywhere on his board instead of playing a normal Chess move. [Bughouse Chess - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bughouse_chess)

I have a BughouseMatch object that contains 2 properties of type BughouseGame - these are the 2 games being played simultaneously.

The BughouseGame object inherits from Game, which is a regular independant Chess game. BughouseGame contains the property "link", which is set to be a reference to the other BughouseGame. It allowes passing pieces between the games and communicating that a victory was achieved in one of the games.

It also contains the property players, which is an array of the 2 players (of type Player) of opposing teams, one playing White and the other Black.
The problem I encountered is that I don't know what is the correct way to keep the score of the match - where to put a property that keeps the number of wins of each team?

It seems natural that the score will be kept in BughouseMatch, but I can't access it from BughouseGame since it's a property of BughouseMatch.
What I ended up doing is creating a Score object which is referenced from the 2 teammates in each team (the Black player in one board and the White in the other), in which there's a property that keeps the number of wins of the team.
I never did anything like that - where 2 objects point to the same instance of another object, and it feels like a mistake.
It's easier to understand it with the diagram I made:
[Image of the relations between objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXF4E.png)

I'd love to hear your opinion about my ideas of making the "link" property in each BughouseGame, and making the shared "Score" object in the players who are teammates. Also, if you have an idea of how this problem could be solved in C#, which is a proper OOP language, I'd love to hear that as well.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"C#, which is a proper OOP language"* - JavaScript is a proper OO language - a language doesn't have to have class-based inheritance like C# or Java in order to be OO. Regarding two different objects both pointing to the same other object, there's nothing inherently wrong about that.

Comment: Have you ever made a game in JS before? Normal chess? Poker? Black Jack? Dice? Tic-tac-toe? Do you have any code already done?

Comment: I do have a working version of the game already, I'm asking this question so that I could understand OOP better. I don't really want to publish the game here because I want to eventually publish it as an app using PhoneGap.

Comment: http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: I think you have failed to understand the basics of JS OOP. In essence the thing to note about object referencing in JS is that you are passing pointers around and not the objects so it's OK to link it like that... if I understood correctly how you did it.

Comment: @Idra, of course I understand that, and as I said my game is complete and working well. I'm trying to understand best OOP practices, not if what I did technically works.

Comment: So your question boils down to what is the best practice for object referencing in JS? Form what I understand you have done nothing wrong that would make a seasoned JS developer cringe.

Answer (score -3):

Focusing on your question title of 'How to access a parent object in JS?' There are a few options. You can use jQuery:

```
 $(this).closest('selector');
```

Or plain JS (you can use any document method):

```
parent.getElementById('Id');
```

If you have to use JS and need to traverse up a hierarchy you can do stuff like this, though I don't recommend it:

```
parent.parent.parent.Method();
```

Also:  [jQuery parent of a parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966408/jquery-parent-of-a-parent)

Comment: Based on your answer, I am fairly certain you read only the title and absolutely nothing in the OP.  This isn't all that helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as @Goblinlord mentions the question is about accessing a parent JS object (as in accessing the object that contains a property object from the property) and whether or not it's the correct way of doing things, it's not about parent DOM element.