# How to get the ID of a row when clicking the button in the same row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the row number of the data table in html using javascript but it always returned undefined.

Is there anyway to get the row number in the data table using a button inside the same row?

for reference please see image:
[image]

I want to get the `row.ciCODe` when the button with the same row is clicked.

can someone help me to do that?

And the code behind that is this :

Table

```
  $('#AccountList').append('<tr data-empid="' + row.ci_ID + '">'
                + '<td  text-align:center;">' + row.ciCODe + '</td>'
                + '<td  text-align:center;">' + row.FullName + '</td>'
                + '<td  text-align:center;">' + row.LoanType + '</td>'
                + '<td  text-align:center;">' + row.Bank + '</td>'
                + '<td  text-align:center;">' + row.Amount + '</td>'
                + '<td  text-align:center;"><label class="'+ xLabel +'"><h6>' + xText + '</h6></label></td>'            
                + '<td  text-align:center;"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary" id="btnPreview" name="btnPreview"><i class="icofont icofont-prescription"></i></button>'
                + '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-outline-danger" id="btnReinvestigate" name="btnReinvestigate"><i class="icofont icofont-redo"></i></button>'
                +'</td>'
                + '</tr>');
```

Button

```
$('#AccountList')
          .on('click', 'button[name="btnPreview"]', function (cId) {
            var ID = $('#AccountList').attr('data-empid');
            alert(ID);
          });
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*jQuery parent of a parent*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966408/jquery-parent-of-a-parent) (or of many [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%5Bjquery%5D+get+tr+parent)).

Comment: You can add an attribute for the button. `<button targer-id='+ row.ci_ID +'>`, and get `var ID = $(this).attr('targer-id')`

Comment: @jimmy , Thank you sir! that work :D